# LWUIT List with changed ListModel

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-list

I have a `List` in LWUIT. My problem is this. When I press FIRE key in one of the elements of the `List`,the selected item changes an attribute so the model of the `List`change, and when I  try to continue going down the `List`lose the focus.

I try to reload the new model, to repaint the `Form`, to repaint the `List`, but nothing seems to work. I always lose focus when I change the model.

What can I do?

Comment: i think it would be better to explain with code. It would be much clearer the problem you have and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Ok, I will try to post my code in a few hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `myList.setHandlesInput(true);` in your event code.